# How to get Session ID in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I made a login application with 2 text field `username`, `password` and web view for after login. Here url

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://website.com/tr/webservicelogin?_username=\(vc.username)&_password=\(vc.password)&status=login&mobil=true")!)
```

When I enter the `username` and `password` these are display session id on webview page. I want to get this session id from cookie after login. Any idea?

Comment: You're sending the password in plain text in the URL?!

Comment: yes i sending plain text @EricAya

Comment: Its just for get session id not login through this link

Comment: Still, anybody can intercept the password and use it later. Bad practice. :)

Comment: @EricAya how you intercept `https` requests? I don't speak about MITM, or server side http access logs.

Comment: @user1516873 I could be wrong, of course, as this is not my domain of expertise, but in OP's example the password is not posted as part of the request, it's in the URL.

Comment: @BurakŞentürk Usually, server returns good http status code (200) and `Set-cookie` header, with sessionID value

Comment: @EricAya sure it is bad (mainly because any http server will log its request and password will stored in logs), but not _insane_ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44716/is-it-possible-to-intercept-https-traffic-and-see-the-links

Answer (score 1):

The **backend** is the one who is responsible for session management. When you are requesting the backend for login, **backend** creates a session for you and passes you the session identifier back. Since this moment, your other requests inside your **client** headers should contain session identifier, according to which backend identifies session user.

Apple has created `NSHTTPCookieStorage` API for managing that in a client side: [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nshttpcookiestorage).

In case you are creating a sample login application, you shouldn't mess with cookies.

P.S. You don't want to send user credentials unencrypted (security violation).